# How to get registration_ids from device group?

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/device-group#managing_device_groups
At this point, it is proposed to create a device group by passing registration_ids there. Is it possible to get a list of devices in a group through the API, knowing the group ID and having admin access to the project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From reading that documentation it seems there is no API to get the registration IDs for a device group. If you need this functionality, you'll need to maintain an (additional) mapping for it yourself.